# is it possible to send JUnit test report by email?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, ant, junit

with ant it is possible to run JUnit tests and generate test reports in several formats: text, HTML, XML ..
and it is recurrent to send test results by email to the responsible, so my question: is it possible to use the xml file generated by Junit in order to send a summary(Html) of the test execution?
or is there another better solution to send the results test execution by email?
any help will be appreciated :)
thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also convert the XML file into an HTML using XSL styles within `junitreport` task.
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html

And then use the inbuilt `mail` task to mail this HTML file

```
<mail mailhost="smtp.myisp.com" mailport="1025" subject="Test build">
  <from address="config@myisp.com"/>
  <replyto address="me@myisp.com"/>
  <to address="all@xyz.com"/>
  <message>The ${buildname} nightly build has completed</message>
  <attachments>
    <fileset dir="dist">
      <include name="**/*.html"/>
    </fileset>
  </attachments>
</mail>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the cruise control to build your project and run unit test. http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/, its a very good tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) supports it out of the box, and I found it easier to configure than Cruise Control.

Answer (score 0):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is a very good build-server with support for email notifications of build and test results.